# Создание xsd файла

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. У меня есть отчёт в fastreport. Там есть коннект с определёнными полями из таблицы. Сейчас в таблице появились новые поля. И мне нужно их добавить в коннект. В коде программы я разобрал dataset на xml и xsd файлы. Теперь мне нужно создать новый xsd с новыми полями. Как это можно сделать? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: а как вы это делали раньше? на крайний случай XSD можно редактировать любым текстовым редактором - это такой же XML, только с фиксированными тегами. Посмотрите как там были определены поля вашей таблицы и добавьте по аналогии новые.

Comment: @rdorn уже разобрался. Спасибо. Тема не актуальна.

Comment: @Андрей Вы можете ответить на свой собственный вопрос. Возможно  Ваше решение будет также другим интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как dataset создаётся в коде программы. Поэтому просто xsd файл создаётся по средствам sql запроса к базе. И для того что бы изменить состав полей нужно поменять запрос на нужный.